# Haxe AS3 target, FlashDevelop: embed and use normal, bold and italic style of the same font

Tags: flash, fonts, embed, flashdevelop, haxe

Any suggestion how to embed the proper way bold, italic and normal style of a font?
I want to use it in a TextField.htmlText, with the proper html tag, but not working - only the regular font shows up. If the TextFormat.font is set to the bold font name, then this shows up only.
I don't want to use the font tag.

In FlashDevelop I rightclicked on the fonts, and added to the Library - I tried with auto generated name/ID, and with specified, but no success.
And yes, I set the TextField.embedFonts = true. :)

Any suggestion or solution?
Thanks is advance!

Comment: Have you tried to embrd bold and italic version of font with normal version of the font?

Comment: Yes, I added the bold and italic to the library, too. But I want to embed the TTFs into the now-compiled SWF.

Comment: try var tformat : TextFormat = new TextFormat ('your font name', fontsize, fontcolor) and for the TextField, .setTextFormat(tformat); _AFTER_ you set the .text value

Comment: oh, just realized this is a years old question :D